# How do I fix my CVS commit?

Tags: cvs, myeclipse

Here is the gist of the error message I get when I try committing some code to a CVS server.

The server reported an error while performing the "cvs commit" command.
[Project Name Here]: cvs [commit aborted]: could not find desired version 1.6 in [URI for class here] ,v

How do I fix this to recognize the new code? Can I set back the version number in MyEclipse Blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes because of Versioning problem between your local and CVS repository. To solve this ,,

1. Take backup of your file .
2. Replace your file from cvs .(Right Click --> Replace With --> Latest from Head).
   It will force your file to replace with the cvs version.
3. Merge your changes with any other tools like WinMerge.
4. Commit your changes now

Answer (score 2):

Move your files out of the way, update to get the cvs version, put your files back and commit.